# Script# 0.8 not found via NuGet

Tags: script#

This is an absolute beginner question. I cloned the Script# github repository (nikhilk/scriptsharp) and am attempting to build the sample KOWorld. When that project tries to restore NuGet packages, it fails on the three ScriptSharp packages that call for version 0.8 saying that the version can not be found. Do I just need to build from the master bracnch and install the resulting vsix (and remove the nuget packages)?

Comment: Nothing like answering my own question. I went ahead and built script# from the current source, modified the manifest to allow deployment in VS2013, and added the 'local' nuget repository. I can run the 'KOWorld" example (after manually copying the scripts retrieved by nuget from the 'packages' directories to the 'scripts' directory).

[I can't mark this as an answer as I am newly registered on stackoverflow]

Answer (score 0):

Glad you figured it out. I have an article here on [getting started with 0.8](https://github.com/theoutlander/scriptsharp/wiki/Using-the-development-branch):

EDIT

VS2013 is now supported. Also, here's a [Hello World](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/wiki/Creating-your-first-HTML5-Application%3a-Hello-World) tutorial.